# Setting project paths in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, pipenv

I can't seem to open project csvs in Jupyter Lab using their project path. Using absolute path works fine:

```
sheet = pandas.read_csv("absolute/path/to/my/table.csv", index_col=[0])
```

But the local path returns a FileNotFoundError:

```
sheet = pandas.read_csv("my_table.csv", index_col=[0])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my_table.csv'
```

If I open python in the same terminal running pipenv and use the same line using the project path (`sheet = pandas.read_csv("my_table.csv", index_col=[0])`), it loads just fine.

I expected I would be able to use local project paths in jupyter if it runs in pipenv, but I appear to be mistaken - is there a way to, say, designate project directories in jupyter so I could use relative paths for project files?

Comment: Does `!ls` include `my_table.csv`?

Comment: terminal may start work in different folder - first check "Current Working Directory" in terminal `pwd` and in code `os.getcwd()` (or `!pwd`). In code you may need to change folder to read data without path - `os.chdir(...)` or `!cd ...`

Comment: @krassowski Oh wow, I didn't know you could do that. It doesn't - it starts from the subdirectory the jupyter notebook is in, which is exactly the information I needed to figure out what's going on and what I need to do instead. Thank you for the help, I'll write up a full solution after work hours.